# GSAP 3+ Tweening values in an array

Tags: javascript, gsap

My use case for this tween is to animate the [morphTargetInfluences](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh.morphTargetInfluences) of an object in THREE.js. The influences are represented as an array like `[0, 1]`.

For simplicity, a mesh is represented like so:

```
mesh = {
  morphTargetInfluences: [0, 1]
}
```

In GSAP 2.0, I could tween this value like so:

```
const target = [1, 0];
TweenMax.to(mesh.morphTargetInfluences, 0.5, { ...target });
```

However with the new API I get a `gsData is undefined` error. Is there a new way to tween array values?

Comment: Hey Chang. The above code [works just fine](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/povjEXw) in GSAP 3. The error with `gsData` must be in a different part of your code. Also, you're much more likely to get a faster response over on [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/).

Answer (score 0):

tl.to(firstArray, duration, secondArray);
In your case and mine too :
tl.to(mesh.morphTargetInfluences, 0.2, targets);